# Chaining type(of:) with an optional type in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2.x you could use `variable?.dynamicType` to do optional chaining on the type only if the variable were non-null.  Is there a way to do the same thing in Swift 3?  `type(of:)` returns a concrete type, and then you have to unwrap the value with an enum which feels very clunky.

Comment: Do you try it at least one time?

Comment: Yes, and I got compiler errors.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: For `struct Foo { var bar: String? }`, `type(of: someOptionalFooInstance?.bar }` compiles but will always return `Optional<String>`, even if `someOptionalFooInstance` is `nil`.